# Laravel Many To Many Polymorphic Relations

Tags: laravel, eloquent, polymorphism, relationships

I have a quick question on how to define the below relationship

I have a `USER` that can belong to Many `Councils`, Many `Schools` and Many `Businesses`.

Now I know I can have a pivot table for all the above something like

```
council_user
school_user
business_user
```

This means I can pull out of the DB all `councils` a `user` belongs to, all `businesses` etc

To save me doing this is there a better approach that having 3 `pivot tables`, could I use Many To Many Polymorphic Relations and do it that way, if so does any one know how that would look as a table structure?

I feel it would be something like...

```
business
id - integer
name - string

council
id - integer
name - string

school
id - integer
name - string

userables
user_id - integer
userable_id - integer
userable_type - string
```

If so do I remove the `userable_is` and `userable_type` from my `USER` table and have this extra `userables` table?

Does any one know how this works, have I totally misunderstood what Polymorphic Relations does?

Answer (score 0):

In Many to Many polymorphic relationship, you should have userables table along with users table. and `userable_id` and `userable_type` should be in userables table not in users table.

**userables table:**

```
user_id   userable_id  userable_type
1         1             App\Business
1         2             App\School
...
```

**Business, School and Council Model:**

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->morphToMany('App\User', 'userable');
}
```

**User Model**:

```
public function businesses()
{
      return $this->morphedByMany('App\User', 'userable');
}

public function schools()
{
      return $this->morphedByMany('App\User', 'userable');
}

public function councils()
{
      return $this->morphedByMany('App\User', 'userable');
}
```

then, this gives all the businesses of user with user_id 1.

```
$users=User::find(1);
foreach($user->businesses as $business)
{
   print_r($business->name);
}
```

See [Many to many polymorphic relation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations) in doc.